# android tablelayout inside linearlayout overflows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to create the following View:

[image]

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="14dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/meals_line_shadow_left" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0" >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textDate"
                        style="@style/MealWizard.BigText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="text"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                     <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/buttonDatePicker"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:paddingRight="7dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/general_date_button_selector" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textTime"
                        style="@style/MealWizard.BigText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="15:34"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/buttonTimePicker"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:paddingRight="7dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/general_time_button_selector" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/meals_line_shadow_right" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that I can't see the right imageView:

[image]

I need solve that without using absolute size (It works with absolute values).

I'll be happy for any suggestions for fixing or alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```
<TableLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:stretchColumns="0" >
```